# Conflict between timed function and user initiated function

Tags: javascript, html

I've been messing around with this bit a javascript that I wrote from the ground up and it works fairly well except for one small issue i've encountered recently. The purpose of the code is to create a rather simple slideshow that cycles through photos automatically (every 5 seconds).

The issue arose when I added in the functionality to allow a user to select a photo in the series by clicking a link. Now as the user continues clicking through photos the 5 second duration decreases drastically and I can't figure out what causes it.

I've copied all the code needed to recreate and test code to JSFiddle, if anyone cares to take a look and offer some constructive criticism.

http://jsfiddle.net/h8Act/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time the user click those links they start another "round" of `sireTimer()`, hence starting another `setTimeout` so it looks like the time between rotations has shortened when in fact, there are multiple instances of your function firing the rotation functionality.

Try adding a flag, to avoid starting addicional `setTimeout`s

Comment: Thanks, I tried several methods with no luck, but taking your solution I created a global variable (count = 0) and incremented it each time sireTimer() executed and added a check at the beginning of sireTimer()  to clearTimeout(duration) if (count > 1).

Answer (score 0):

I'd not memorize the timeout in a single var but in a array

```
durations = [];

/* ... */

// in sireTimer
    // cancel all timeouts
for (var i=0; i< durations.length; i++) {
   clearTimeout(durations[i])
}
    // clear timeout array
durations = [];
durations.push(setTimeout ...)
```

It may be possible that channging windows and tabs start some timeouts as well. So just clear all timeouts

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I wasn't able to get the code to work using this method, but keep it in mind if I run into a similar issue in the future.